# count co-ocurrence sorted vector string c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have a sorted vector of strings, I am trying to find the coocurrence of every element in the vector:

V = {"AAA","AAA","AAA","BCA",...}

```
int main()
{
      vector<string> vec;
      //for every word in the vector
      for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size();i++)
       {

             int counter = 0;
              //loop through the vector and count the coocurrence of this word
             for(size_t j = 0; j < vec.size();j++)
              {
                 if(vec[i] == vec[j]) counter +=1;
              }

              cout << vec[i] << "    "<<counter <<ed,l
         }
}
```

The complexity is O(n^2) right? THis is taking so much time how can I find a way to solve it?

Thank you,

That's the edit:

```
int main()
{
      vector<string> vec;
      //for every word in the vector
      for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size();i++)
       {

             int counter = 0;
              //loop through the vector and count the coocurrence of this word
             for(size_t j = i+1; j < vec.size()-1;j++)
              {
                 if(vec[i] == vec[j]) counter +=1;
              }

              cout << vec[i] << "    "<<counter <<ed,l
         }
}
```

Comment: Is it already sorted ?

Comment: @hivert yes the vector is already sorted

Comment: Even if it wasn't sorted, it's trivial to cut the runtime of this in half.  `for(size_t j=i+1; ...)`

Comment: @MooingDuck: But then it is still O(n*n)

Comment: yes it will be O(n^2 )

Comment: @Nawaz: Sure, it'd still be N^2, and silly slow, but twice as fast as it was previously.

Comment: If you can use a map from the beginning, it's fairly easy.

Comment: @chris I'll try to see how to use the map in c++; I saw a post where they used map. I never used it. I'll take a look at it also.

Comment: nah it's not O(N^2), it's O(N^2 * |S|), roughly O(N^3). comparing 2 strings takes O(|S|) or to say in plain O(N) runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not tested. I assume that the vector contains at least one element.

```
counter = 1
for(size_t i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++)
  {
    if(vec[i] == vec[i-1]) counter +=1;
    else 
      {
         std::cout << vec[i-1] << ", " << counter << std::endl;
         counter = 1;
      }
  }
std::cout << vec[i-1] << ", " << counter << std::endl;
```

This is clearly O(n). There is a slight difference from your code: each word is printed only once.

Comment: So by this for every word, as long as it's the same I add +1 to the counter till it's different.

Comment: [so close](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=942248cd3de20ce35a6ebcdb7f28a5f3-76514b8f9424a3be7ad7d477f762fdd0).  Oh, you edited a comment in about the zero element case :P

Comment: @Mooing Duck. Read My assumption at the begginning of the post.

Comment: It did really change. I was expecting to finish the counting by tomorrow noon.
I know it's not the right way to measure the time but just an approximation:
Run1: 5.081, Run2: 6.053, Run3: 5.068

Comment: i'll try the algorithm of  H2CO3

Comment: @HaniGoc: N^2 is really much larger that N when N=10^6 !

Comment: @hivert: This is O(N*|S|) at least, roughly O(N^2). Comparing 2 strings take O(|S|) runtime where `|S|=length of string S`

Comment: @Fallen. In my mind (as in the example), the size of the string were fixed = k. In this case this is O(kN) = k O(N) since k is constant = O(N).

Answer (score 3):

Tested, O(n), works even if the vector is not sorted or if it's empty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "aaa", "abc", "aaa", "def", "aaa", "aaa", "abc", "ghi" };
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        m[*it]++;

    for (std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
        std::cout << it->first << " -> " << it->second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or, the appropriate snippet re-written using range-based loops for the sake of readability (thanks Frerich Raabe):

```
for (const auto it: v)
    m[it]++;

for (const auto it: m)
    std::cout << it.first << " -> " << it.second << std::endl;
```

Comment: However, its O(n) memory whereas my solution is O(1).

Comment: @hivert However, the requirement was a tighter-bound running time, not lower memory usage.

Comment: If you use `std::unordered_map` and initializer lists, you could just as well use range-based for loops and `auto` to shorten your code considerably, e.g. `for ( const auto &s: v ) m[s]++;`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Please don't be too acid ;-) I would still bet that my code is faster that yours...

Comment: i'll try both very interesting. I have a vector of size 106207. thank you so much

Comment: @hivert It may very well be faster - as we all know, asymptotic complexity is asymptotic and not "identical" for a reason.